# UpdatePanel Gridview not updating

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-ajax

For some reason, I can't get the Gridview in the Updatepanel to refresh after I've made changes. can someone help?

I'm using the ToolkitScriptManager control and the UpdatePanel.

```
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server" UpdateMode="Conditional">
   <ContentTemplate>
        <asp:GridView blah...

         </asp:GridView>

    </ContentTemplate>
   <Triggers>
       <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="DeleteButton" EventName="Click" />
       <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="IBUpUp" EventName="Click" />
       <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="IBDownDown" EventName="Click" />
       <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="IBUp" EventName="Click" />
       <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="IBDown" EventName="Click" />
       <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="EditProfile" EventName="Click" />
   </Triggers>
```

Cs Page

```
protected void Unnamed3_Click(object sender, ImageClickEventArgs e)
        {

            int rowIndex = GridView1.SelectedIndex;
            GridViewRow gvr = GridView1.SelectedRow;

            if (rowIndex >= 0)
            {
                //delete

                String GridViewOne = GridView1.DataKeys[rowIndex].Value.ToString();

                //delete image

                string imagename = gvr.Cells[2].Text;

                string pathToImage = @"C:\Images\";

                pathToImage = pathToImage + imagename;


                if (System.IO.File.Exists(pathToImage))
                {
                    // Use a try block to catch IOExceptions, to
                    // handle the case of the file already being
                    // opened by another process.
                    try
                    {
                        System.IO.File.Delete(pathToImage);
                    }
                    catch (System.IO.IOException m)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine(m.Message);
                        return;
                    }
                }

                int bannerid = Convert.ToInt32(GridViewOne); 

                SqlDataReader sdr = null;

                SqlConnection conn = GetConnection();

                SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("Tool_DeleteBannerAds", conn);

                cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

                SqlParameter param1 = new SqlParameter();

                param1.ParameterName = "@BannerID";
                param1.Value = bannerid;

                cmd.Parameters.Add(param1);

                conn.Open();

                sdr = cmd.ExecuteReader();

                sdr.Close();

                UpdatePanel1.Update();
                GridView1.DataBind();

            }
            else
            {
                //don't do anything
                //keep
                //Response.Redirect("Default.aspx");
            }


        }
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

change the order:

```
 GridView1.DataBind();
 UpdatePanel1.Update();
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is my code for your question

**ASPX FILE**

```
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" EnablePageMethods="true" runat="server">
    </asp:ScriptManager>
    <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" UpdateMode="Conditional" runat="server">
        <ContentTemplate>
            <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False">
                <Columns>
                    <asp:BoundField HeaderText="Name List" DataField="EmpName" />
                </Columns>
            </asp:GridView>
        </ContentTemplate>
        <Triggers>
            <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="Button1" EventName="Click" />
        </Triggers>
    </asp:UpdatePanel>

    <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Button" OnClick="Button1_Click1" />
    </form>
</body>
```

**CODE BEHIND FILE**

```
 protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!Page.IsPostBack)
        {
            var Employee = new { EmpID = 1, EmpName = "Rahul Jain", Department = "IT", Age = 33, Address = "Hello" };
            var customerList = (new[] { Employee }).ToList();
            customerList.Add(new { EmpID = 2, EmpName = "Sheetal Jain", Department = "IT", Age = 33, Address = "Hello" });
            GridView1.DataSource = customerList;
            GridView1.DataBind();
        }
    }
    protected void Button1_Click1(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            var Employee = new { EmpID = 1, EmpName = "Rahul Jain", Department = "IT", Age = 33, Address = "Hello" };
            var customerList = (new[] { Employee }).ToList();
            customerList.Add(new { EmpID = 2, EmpName = "Sheetal Jain", Department = "IT", Age = 33, Address = "Hello" });
            customerList.Add(new { EmpID = 2, EmpName = "Minakshi Jain", Department = "IT", Age = 33, Address = "Hello" });
            GridView1.DataSource = customerList;
            GridView1.DataBind();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw ex;
        }
    }
```

This Code Dosent Created the postback for me hope it will work for you as well....

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative, you could set the UpdateMode parameter to "Always" (which is the default) to allow any web control that triggers a postback to automatically update the GridView.

This saves you a few lines of code (configuring the triggers) but will also help if you dynamically add controls to your GridView that will also trigger postback events on your page.