# Gridview Doesn't Refresh After CheckedChanged?

Tags: asp.net, gridview

I have a gridview with Template field. I add a checkbox in templatefield . Autopostback is true for checkbox .

I fill grid in Load-page and creted column dynamic .

```
 if (!IsPostBack)
        {
         FillGrid();
        }
```

I use update panel

```
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server">
 <ContentTemplate>
<SharePoint:SPGridView ID="grid" AllowSorting="true" AllowFiltering="true"    CssClass="ms-listviewtable"  
runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="false">
<RowStyle CssClass="ms-alternating" Height="10px" />
<Columns>
    <asp:TemplateField> 
        <ItemTemplate  >
            <asp:CheckBox ID="select" runat="server" 
                OnCheckedChanged="select_CheckedChanged" AutoPostBack="true"  />
            <input id="Display" type="hidden" runat="server" />
            <input id="itemID" type="hidden" runat="server" />
            <asp:Image ID="icon" runat="server" Height="10px" Visible="false"  />
        </ItemTemplate>
        <ItemStyle Width="35px" />
    </asp:TemplateField>
    <asp:TemplateField >
     </asp:TemplateField>
</Columns>
</SharePoint:SPGridView>
 </ContentTemplate>
  <Triggers>
<asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="select" EventName="OnCheckedChanged" />
 </Triggers>
 </asp:UpdatePanel>
```

but show  error :A control with ID 'select' could not be found for the trigger in UpdatePanel 'UpdatePanel1'.

My problem is : When checkbox is change, page refresh

**I don't want to refresh page after checkedchange!**

Comment: If autopostback is true for checkbox then the page will refresh , you could try to use update panel for partial page refresh

Comment: I use Update panel . plz see question, i edit

Comment: What does your FillGrid method look like? SO has a simular question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5476766/updatepanel-gridview-not-updating

Comment: I bind grid in FillGrid(). I have a special column that is Linkbutton and they  fill in RowDataBound . when page refresh , they do'y bind.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all you need changes templetecolumn as below

```
<asp:TemplateField>
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:CheckBox ID="chkselect" runat="server" />
                <input id="Display" type="hidden" runat="server" />
                <input id="itemID" type="hidden" runat="server" />
                <asp:Image ID="imgicon" runat="server" Height="10px" Style="display: none;" ImageUrl="~/images/arrow_left.jpg" />
            </ItemTemplate>
            <ItemStyle Width="35px" />
        </asp:TemplateField>
```

Now handle itemdatabound event in server side code

```
Protected Sub SPGridView_RowDataBound(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridViewRowEventArgs) Handles gvBanner.RowDataBound
    If e.Row.RowType = DataControlRowType.DataRow Then
        Dim chkselect As CheckBox = e.Row.FindControl("chkselect")
        Dim imgicon As Image = e.Row.FindControl("imgicon")
        If chkselect IsNot Nothing Then
            chkselect.Attributes.Add("onclick", "javascript:DoMyTask(this,'" + imgicon.ClientID + "')")
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

Now specify JavaScript function in aspx page as below.

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
    function DoMyTask(obj, imgid) {            
        var objCheck = obj.checked;
        var objimg = document.getElementById(imgid)
        if (objCheck == true) {
            objimg.style.display = "block";
            //set more attributes over here
        }
        else {
            objimg.style.display = "none";
            //set more attributes over here
        }
        var count = $(":checkbox:checked").length;
        alert('you have selected ' + count + ' Rows');
    }

</script>
```

Hope this will help you...happy coding ..

Comment: Thanks a lot :).But how do i count selected row?

Comment: selected row means the row having checkbox checked right ?? and you need to count those rows having tick mark chekbox right ??

Comment: yes, I want count selected row , and add Attributes  for a linkbutton control on page and enable this.

Comment: you can get count by  using $(":checkbox:checked").length; this. i will modify js function .add count in alert

Comment: i have tested it..you can use this code. when you checked checkbox it will alert msg for how many rows you have selected. :)

Comment: Thanks a lot :). Sorry , How i add a Attributes  for a control in javascript :(

Comment: simillar way you can get control id in js and set attribute in same js function.

Answer (score 1):

you have to set autopostback="false" or remove autopostback property in checkbox. autopostback actully refresh the page.

Comment: can you please specify what u want to do in checkbox change event ? is it possible to accomplish your task using client side event ??

Comment: I want add a Attributes for a control. and visible a control if row selected is one.

Comment: you can do your task using handling client side event.  simply write a javascript function pass the control's id and set attributes and visibility in js function.

Comment: No, i should reed all row  and   change Attributes  for a control .

Comment: why you need to read all row ?? cant you pass Image Client Id in each checkbox onclick function ? function will take care of single object only..

Comment: I use this code for get id: HtmlInputHidden itemIDCtl = (HtmlInputHidden)grid.Rows[i].FindControl("itemID");   ... I should count checked row for enable/disable a control .(if count is 1 enable else disable)

Comment: Shall i post another answer for accomplish your task using javascript funtion ??

Answer (score 1):

So what happens if you set the autopostback property of the checkbox to false?

Also if you are actually looking to handle the onchange event of the checkbox you could wrap the grid with an UpdatePanel; the user wouldn't see a postback but you still get the flexibility of serverside event handling.

Comment: grid have not autopostback property.