# why my bound field not working inside grid view with update pane?

Tags: asp.net, gridview, updatepanel

i have a grid view inside update panel with multiple bound fields the last two bound field as shown in image when click show another grid view without post back but download not working except i set EnablePartialRendering="false" of script-manager
but in this case updatepanel not working to show bound field

[image]

```
    <asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1"  runat="server">  
 </asp:ScriptManager>  
 <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server" >  
<contenttemplate>  

 <div id="DivImages" runat="server" visible="false" class="block rnd">
            <div class="title2">الأحكـــــــــــام</div>
            <div class="content2">

     <asp:gridview ID="GvImages" runat="server"  PagerStyle-CssClass="pages"   AllowPaging="True" 
                        AutoGenerateColumns="False" CellSpacing="-1" Width="100%" DataKeyNames="DocCode,IssuesID" 
       CssClass="dataGrid"   OnPageIndexChanging="GvImages_PageIndexChanging" GridLines="None" 
                        PageSize="20" OnRowCommand="GvImages_RowCommand" 
                        OnSelectedIndexChanging="GvImages_SelectedIndexChanging">
<AlternatingRowStyle BackColor="White" />
<Columns>

<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="رقم السجــل">   
     <ItemTemplate>
             <%# Container.DataItemIndex + 1 %>   
     </ItemTemplate>
 </asp:TemplateField>


 <asp:BoundField DataField="DocCode" HeaderText="رقم الحكم/ القرار"   SortExpression="DocCode" />
    <asp:BoundField DataField="IssuesNum" HeaderText="كود القضيه" 
        SortExpression="IssuesNum" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="TypeName" HeaderText="نوع القضيه" 
        SortExpression="TypeName" />
         <asp:BoundField DataField="Year" HeaderText="السنه" 
        SortExpression="Year" />

            <asp:BoundField DataField="Area" HeaderText="المنطقه" 
        SortExpression="Area" />



      <asp:BoundField DataField="DocTypeName" HeaderText="تصنيــف المستند" SortExpression="DocTypeName" />

    <asp:BoundField DataField="Name" HeaderText="نوع المستند" 
        SortExpression="Name" />

            <asp:TemplateField  HeaderText="حذف">

                            <ItemTemplate>
                                <asp:LinkButton ID="cmd_DeleteRow"   CommandName="DeleteRow"  CssClass="delete" ToolTip="حذف" CommandArgument="<%# ((GridViewRow)Container).RowIndex %>" runat="server" OnClientClick="return confirmDeleteRow()" />
                            </ItemTemplate>
                            <HeaderStyle Width="125px" />
                        </asp:TemplateField>

      <asp:CommandField SelectText="عرض"  HeaderText="عرض" ShowHeader="True" ShowSelectButton="True">  
                    <HeaderStyle HorizontalAlign="Right" />
                    </asp:CommandField>

                        <asp:TemplateField  HeaderText="تحميل">

                            <ItemTemplate>
                                <asp:LinkButton ID="DownLoad" CommandName="DownLoad"   Text="تحميل" ToolTip="تحميل" CommandArgument="<%# ((GridViewRow)Container).RowIndex %>" runat="server" />
                            </ItemTemplate>
                            <HeaderStyle Width="125px" />
                        </asp:TemplateField>


</Columns>
  <RowStyle Height="25px" />
                    <HeaderStyle Height="30px" />
                    <PagerStyle CssClass="pages" Wrap="false" />
</asp:gridview>

</div>
</div>


 </contenttemplate>
 <Triggers>
```

in button search i bind my grid

like in this code

```
    protected void ShowDoc(string sCondition)
    {
    //declare connection by pass connection string from web.config
    SqlConnection sqlcon = new SqlConnection
        (ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["SystemConn"].ConnectionString);

    //declare sql statment  as astring variable

    if (Session["Image"] != null)
    {
        Session.Remove("Image");
    }
    try
    {
        SqlStatment = string.Format("select distinct IssuesNum,DocType,DocTypeSub,DocCode,DocTypeName,Name,IssuesID,TypeID,TypeName,Area,IssuesNumSplited,Year   from [View_ImagesSearch] Where {0}  Order By [IssuesNumSplited] ASC", sCondition);

        //create asql command and pass for it the connection string and sql statment
        SqlCommand sqlcom = new SqlCommand(SqlStatment, sqlcon);

        //create data adaptor to bring data from database
        SqlDataAdapter sad = new SqlDataAdapter(sqlcom);

        // declare dataset to store data from data base in it
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();

        //fill data set with data adabter that contain data from database
        sad.Fill(ds);
        lblDocCount2.Text = ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count.ToString();
        Session["Image"] = ds;
        GvImages.DataSource = ds;
        GvImages.DataBind();

    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        par_ErrorMessage.Visible = true;
        par_ErrorMessage.InnerText = ex.Message;
    }
   }
```

when i click command called عرض  updatepanel work to show another gridview 
but when iclick item template download not workink fine untill i set EnablePartialRendering="False"

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you are calling *Update* on the `UpdatePanel` after you call *DataBind* on the `GridView`:

```
GridView.DataBind();
UpdatePanel.Update();
```

See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5476766/updatepanel-gridview-not-updating) for other possible solutions.

Comment: thanks for replay but when type this code and updatemode vecame condional my show boundfield not firing even now ?

Comment: Can you edit your original question with some more code (markup for the GridView and a snippet from the code behind where you are calling DataBind)?

Comment: Try setting `UpdateMode=Conditional` on `UpdatePanel1` and in your code behind, do `GvImages.DataBind(); `UpdatePanel.Update();`