# gridview bind with data is not visible in the browser using vb .net

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, gridview

i have a scenario where gridview bind with data is not visible in the browser on vb .net .The same solution is  working on other pc but only in my pc it is not working means gridview with bind data is not visible in the browser.
gridview is inside  update panel
<

```
asp:UpdatePanel ID="abcPan" runat="server">
           <ContentTemplate>
 <asp:Button ID="btnShowCard" runat="server" Text="Show card" CssClass="btn btn-block " />
        <asp:GridView ID="grdCardView" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" CssClass="table table-striped table-hover table-bordered dataTable no-footer"                                                 EmptyDataText="No card" EnableModelValidation="True">   
     <Columns>
    .
    .
     </Columns>
        </asp:GridView>
        </ContentTemplate>
        </asp:UpdatePanel>
```

vb code
on click of button data is binding on gridview.

```
Protected Sub btnShowCard_Click(sender As Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnShowCard.Click
        .
        .
        grdCardView.DataSource = objReports.ToArray
        grdCardView.DataBind()
        End Sub
    
  

      

Protected Sub grdCardView_RowDataBound(sender As Object, e As System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridViewRowEventArgs) Handles grdCardView.RowDataBound
    .
    .
    End Sub
```

I tried a lot but not able to diagnose how same piece of code working on other pc but not working on my pc when run through visual studio.Any idea would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

In your code, you have mentioned "AutoGeneratedColumns"="False". So you need to mention the Columns explicitly. As there is no columns defined to render, you are unable to see the gridview with populated data. Either you need to set AutogeneratedColumns ="True" or you need to define the columns with in grid view markup.

Comment: columns are mentioned inside gridview already ,i haven't mentioned there. let me update question

Comment: Where is you button located, is it outside the update panel. Complete markup will help

Comment: button is inside update panel ,i have updated markup

Comment: Please have a look in this thread https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5476766/updatepanel-gridview-not-updating

Comment: i tried the link you mentioned above but still it not rendered , same code is rendering data when run through vs on other machine

Comment: Can you please ensure objPolicies has data.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/226605/discussion-between-sam-and-chandu).